# Get current user on root script ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I write a script for the network dispatcher in `/etc/NetworkDispatcher/dispatcher.d/`.
How can I get the current logged user?

I already tried these commands :

```
$USER
$LOGNAME
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Who runs the script? Are you wanting the user running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use "last":

```
$ last | grep "logged in"
```

Answer (score 5):

If running a script with /usr/bin/sudo you can access the original user from the $SUDO_USER environment variable.

For example if this is the contents of a script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "USER:      $USER"
echo "SUDO_USER: $SUDO_USER"
```

Then if you run it as "alex":

```
alex@yuzu:~$ ./test.sh 
USER:      alex
SUDO_USER:
```

And if you run it via sudo:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ sudo ./test.sh
USER:      root
SUDO_USER: alex
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `whoami`. Or perhaps you could get a list of users logged-in with `users`. It really depends on what you need specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a postins script in a deb file, nothing of the above worked, but this did on LinuxMint 19.3 (tricia):

```
`users`
```